# Minimizer over set of $C^1$ functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

Exercise (1.4) of Renardy and Rogers: "An introduction to partial differential equations" asks to

> Show that there is an infinite family of minimizers of
> $$
>  J(u) = \int_0^1 (1-u'(t)^2)^2\,dt
>  $$
> over the set of all piecewise $C^1$ functions satisfying $u(0)=u(1)=0$.

Now the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation is

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left[4 (1-u'(t)^2) u'(t) \right] = 0.
$$

I would argue that the equation above has no solutions satisfying the given boundary conditions. Integrating once leaves us with

$$
(1-u'(t)^2) u'(t) = C
$$

and, depending on $C$, there might be zero to three solutions. However, any solution, if it exists, requires $u'(t)=\mathrm{const}$ and, consequently, $u(t)$ is linear and hence cannot satisfy the boundary conditions (except for the trivial solution).

I suspect that the key to the solution lies in the fact that we allow piecewise $C^1$ functions. However, I cannot see how we could employ that. Doesn't any discontinuity in the first derivative show up as a ($\delta$) source term in the Euler-Lagrange equation?

I'd be grateful for any pointers. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Normally a piecewise $C^1$ function is implicitly assumed to be continuous. Is this also the case in Renardy and Rogers?

Comment: @Qmechanic They don't really say specifically but I would assume so. Given the solution this assumptions seems reasonable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without solving the Euler-Lagrange equation, it's clear that $J(u)$ is minimized when $1-(u'(t))^2=0$, or $u'(t)=\pm 1$. Here are some examples of piecewise $C^1$ functions satisfying $u(0)=u(1)=0$ and such that $u'(t)=\pm 1$:
\begin{align}
u_{1}(t)&=
\begin{cases}
t,&\text{if}\,\,0\leq t\leq\frac{1}{2}, \\
-t+1,&\text{if}\,\,\frac{1}{2}<t\leq 1,
\end{cases} \\
u_{2}(t)&=
\begin{cases}
t,&\text{if}\,\,0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{4}, \\
-t+\frac{1}{2},&\text{if}\,\,\frac{1}{4}<t\leq \frac{3}{4}, \\
t-1,&\text{if}\,\,\frac{3}{4}<t\leq 1,
\end{cases} \\
u_{3}(t)&=
\begin{cases}
t,&\text{if}\,\,0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{4}, \\
-t+\frac{1}{2},&\text{if}\,\,\frac{1}{4}<t\leq \frac{1}{2}, \\
t-\frac{1}{2},&\text{if}\,\,\frac{1}{2}<t\leq\frac{3}{4}, \\
-t+1,&\text{if}\,\,\frac{3}{4}<t\leq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was too fixated on the Euler-Lagrange equation to see that.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it has to do something with the piecewise regularity condition.

Hint: Does a solution to the minimization problem really have to have constant derivative?

Concerning the EL-equation: It seems correct, but I would read it in a weak sense (if your are familiar with that).